# merge 2 collections of similar document structure together for aggregation query

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections which have a similar document structure besides one has some additional fields. I have written an aggregation for data I need for one of these collections but I would rather prefer merging these collections into one before aggregating so I dont have to run that aggregation twice. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Have you checked out [$unionWith](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/)?

Comment: thank you I think this is what I was looking for. I was already stuck on lookup but the data is unrelated so that didnt help. I ll try unionWith otherwise come back to this. Cheers